# "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index" when trying to modify column values a pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe:

```
       A         C         D
0    one  0.410599 -0.205158
1    one  0.144044  0.313068
2    one  0.333674 -0.742165
3  three  0.761038 -2.552990
4  three  1.494079  2.269755
5    two  1.454274 -0.854096
6    two  0.121675  0.653619
7    two  0.443863  0.864436
```

Let's assume that `A` is the anchor column. I now want to display each group value *only once*, at the top:

```
        A         C         D
0    one  0.410599 -0.205158
1         0.144044  0.313068
2         0.333674 -0.742165
3  three  0.761038 -2.552990
4         1.494079  2.269755
5    two  1.454274 -0.854096
6         0.121675  0.653619
7         0.443863  0.864436
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
df['A'] = df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['A']\
        .apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('.*', '').set_value(0, x.values[0])).values
```

My strategy was to do a groupby and then set all values to an empty string other than the first. This doesn't seem to work, because I get:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Which means that the output I get is incorrect. Any ideas/suggestions/improvements welcome.

I should add that I am trying to generalise a solution that can single out values at the top OR bottom OR middle of each group, so I'd give more preference to a solution that helps me do that (to understand, the example above shows how to single out values *only at the top of each group*, however, I want to generalise a solution that allows me to single them out at the bottom or in the middle).

Comment: Actually, since data is sorted here, you can just use `df.loc[df.A == df.A.shift(), 'A'] = ''`?

Comment: @Zero You can assume that it is sorted for this case. However, I am trying to generalise a solution that can single out a value at the top OR bottom, OR middle of each group. For this question I've just asked how to single it out at the top of each group. I'll ask a separate question on that, if I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: How would you handle `middle` case when you have even elements?

Comment: @Zero Either side is fine - as long as it is in the middle or near middle.

Comment: @Zero No problem. I can live with separate approaches. I was wondering if it could, because, for example, in my code, the `.set_value(0, x.values[0])` index can be tweaked so that 0 can be changed to anything - such as `len(x) // 2` or something of the sort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method didn't work because of the index error. When you groupby 'A', the index is represented the same way in the grouped data too. Since `set_value(0)` could not find the correct index, it creates a *new object* with that index. That's the reason why there was a length mismatch.

**Fix 1**
*`reset_index(drop=True)`*

```
df['A'] = df.groupby('A')['A'].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('.*', '')\
                      .reset_index(drop=True).set_value(0, x.values[0])).values
df

      A         C         D
0    one  0.410599 -0.205158
1         0.144044  0.313068
2         0.333674 -0.742165
3  three  0.761038 -2.552990
4         1.494079  2.269755
5    two  1.454274 -0.854096
6         0.121675  0.653619
7         0.443863  0.864436
```

---

**Fix 2**
*`set_value`*

[`set_value`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.Series.set_value.html) has a 3rd parameter called `takeable` which determines how the index is treated. It is `False` by default, but setting it to `True` worked for my case.

In addition to [Zero's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46447471/4909087), the solution for isolating values at the centre of their groups is as follows:

```
df.A = df.groupby('A'['A'].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace('.*', '')\
                           .set_value(len(x) // 2, x.values[0], True)).values 

df

       A         C         D
0         0.410599 -0.205158
1    one  0.144044  0.313068
2         0.333674 -0.742165
3         0.761038 -2.552990
4  three  1.494079  2.269755
5         1.454274 -0.854096
6    two  0.121675  0.653619
7         0.443863  0.864436
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the values are sorted, use the `duplicated` method for the first and last cases.

---

**Keep First**

```
In [4233]: df.loc[df.A.duplicated(keep='first'), 'A'] = ''

In [4234]: df
Out[4234]:
       A         C         D
0    one  0.410599 -0.205158
1         0.144044  0.313068
2         0.333674 -0.742165
3  three  0.761038 -2.552990
4         1.494079  2.269755
5    two  1.454274 -0.854096
6         0.121675  0.653619
7         0.443863  0.864436
```

---

**Keep Last**

```
In [4236]: df.loc[df.A.duplicated(keep='last'), 'A'] = ''

In [4237]: df
Out[4237]:
       A         C         D
0         0.410599 -0.205158
1         0.144044  0.313068
2    one  0.333674 -0.742165
3         0.761038 -2.552990
4  three  1.494079  2.269755
5         1.454274 -0.854096
6         0.121675  0.653619
7    two  0.443863  0.864436
```